# transferring FIlemaker DB data to mySQL DB

Tags: mysql, xml, filemaker

My office has a Filemaker database which they asked me to replace with a mySQL one. The mySQL one is now set up and running, but doesn't have *exact* same structure as the Filemaker one (they asked for more things to be added, redundant things were left out, etc.).

I've seen that the filemaker data can be exported as `.xml` files, could I use those to populate the mySQL database?
If so, I've only ever used 
`Cooktop`,but I'm currently using mac10.6/lubuntu, is there maybe an equivalent (free) piece of software that could do that?
All suggestions are welcome.
Thanks

Comment: FileMaker data can also be exported as .csv (as well as other formats). I believe .csv files can easily be imported into MySQL?

Comment: I noticed some new activity on this page. Could you select an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can add some information about the various export formats that FileMaker provides. I've done extensive research and testing on this topic.

Below, you'll see a chart with all of the formats that FileMaker offers along the top. Along the side, you'll see various features of these file formats that are unique to FileMaker when exporting. Some are limitations of the FileMaker export process and others are general pros and cons of the format itself.

I'll explain them briefly:

- Headers: column labels are exported
- Delimiter: the type of separator symbol used
- UTF 8/16: yes if either of these is available, could be of concern for special characters or some languages
- Only 1 format: means that only one type of encoding is available
- Other encoding: a list of all encoding options
- Can be imported: FileMaker allows import (not important for this question)
- Future proof: According to Wikipedia, format is still widely used and actively maintained
- Open standard: open source format
- Size: when exporting one of our tables, this was the size of the file

I would recommend also considering some of these factors when deciding which format will work for you. It will depend on the contents and type of your data.

[image: Format analysis]

Answer (score 2):

MySQL is just the backend database, so you need a UI to perform the import. You could use FileMaker for this as well, if you set up the MySQL database as an ESS source. If you do this, then you can use familiar import steps in FileMaker to populate your new database.

This may be what the previous answer mentions, but just to designate between the ODBC insert via Execute SQL, which is limited, and External SQL Sources (ESS) that give a native UI in FM.

Answer (score 1):

If the FileMaker database is hosted on a server, you could setup an ODBC link to the MySQL. You could then create a script, in FileMaker, to loop through the data, creating rows in MySQL with only the Columns you are looking to populate.

Other than that, you can export the data, from FileMaker, into many other formats including; TAB, CSV, Excel, xml and pushing it into MySQL.

Comment: You don't need a server to work with MySQL via ODBC. However, if you've never done this before, you may find it's not worth the effort for the sake of a one-time data migration.